# HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath() returning inconsistent results

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm hitting a strange problem with `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()`.
If I call

`HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/")`

or

`HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")`

I get back "C:\GitHub\MyWebApp", which is what I'd expect. But if I call

`HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/folder")`

or

`HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/folder")`

I'm getting "C:\folder". I would expect to get "C:\GitHub\MyWebApp\folder"

I don't understand how this could be going wrong.
I'm running .Net 4.6.1 and debugging on Windows using Visual Studio 2019, in case it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afraid this one is a little embarrassing - a script had added a virtual folder in my IIS config and this was redirecting "folder" to "C:\folder". The responses were correct, they just confused me and I didn't spot the configuration before asking the question.

Thanks to anyone who spent time thinking about this one.